# Simple game graphics using Qt library

Tags: c++, image, qt

I want to create a very simple game, something like [this](http://www.miniclip.com/games/crashdown/en/). In general I need several colors of squares, they should appear, disappear, move while you click on them. I have created a `QDialog`. In it I use `MyDialog::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)` function in order to get the coordinates where mouse was clicked. In general I need two more things to programm my game.

1. Put images in my QDialog
2. Move them
3. Remove them form my dialog

Could you give some sample code that adds an image into the dialog, moves it and destroys, please? What is the most convenient way of doing this?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-graphicsview.html (and don't use dialog classes for stuff that isn't, well, a dialog box).

Comment: how about using QML? It's better designed for graphic work as it uses OpenGL

Comment: @Mat I have created the same files http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/graphicsview-collidingmice.html in empty Qt project. And I use QT creator 2.7.0 based on Qt 5.0.2, but it can not find `QGraphicsItem`, `QtWidgets`. Why?

Comment: Did you also take the `.pro` file? (Requires QT += widgets in there.) Qt 5.0's rather new still, might be some bugs left on the site - the examples ship with Qt, you should be able to build those directly (unless you didn't install them with Qt). Read the Qt 5 porting guide too, there's some notes about changes in header structure (notably for QWidget & related classes.)

Comment: Ok , I have found the project in my codes: C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2012_64\examples\widgets\graphicsview\collidingmice\ Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Place and image in specific coordinates in QGraphicsScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180156/place-and-image-in-specific-coordinates-in-qgraphicsscene)

Functions is the code are useful for creating a simple game: `item.setPos`, `scene.addItem` ...