# Place and image in specific coordinates in QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

In the code below I have used `item.setPos(0,0);` in order to place `green.png` in the upper-left corner of my application (`QGraphicsView` actually). But is appears right in the center from both directions - vertically and horizontally. Please help to put the image in 0,0 coordinates.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QIcon>



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    scene.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor(255, 255, 255), Qt::SolidPattern));


    QGraphicsPixmapItem item(QPixmap(":/images/green.png"));
    item.setPos(0,0);
    scene.addItem(&item);


    QGraphicsView view(&scene);
    view.setFixedSize(400, 400);
    view.setWindowTitle("Diamond Dash");
    view.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/images/red.png"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added

```
scene.setSceneRect(0,0, 400, 400);
```

and it worked!